# Where in the OpenJDK javac source should I start looking for a place to get java class metadata?

Tags: lexical-analysis, java

I am planning to start a project part of which requires a lexical analyzer for java source code.  Simply, I need a class list with metadata.  Inheritance hierarchy is enough for now, but eventually I'd like to be able to get more information on the class (such as containing class, and fields/methods with metadata).

I'd like to use OpenJDK to help with this.

Can anyone direct me where in the javac (or other) code I could best begin understanding how openjdk works so that I can fork the javac code and write something to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

There's Java Compiler api for that: [overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javac/index.html) and [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/index.html). The corresponding OpenJDK source code (for JDK 6) is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/langtools/file/df926e17f6d1/src/share/classes/com/sun/source/).